# How to properly close a modal window by clicking outside of the modal window? How does window.onclick work?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I was looking at W3's method of how to close a modal by clicking outside of the modal box. 
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_close

Why does this work? I thought it would be correct if you write `if (event.target !== modal)` to hide the modal. Is there something about window.onclick that I don't understand? Thank you for your help.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>W3.CSS Modal</h2>
  <p>In this example we demonstrate how to close the modal by clicking outside of the modal box.</p>

  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h2>Modal Header</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>You have two options to close this modal:</p>
        <p>Click on the "x" or click anywhere outside of the modal!</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>Modal Footer</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the page, you will see that the `div` with `id01` has:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

That makes the `div` fill the whole page, so wherever you click on the page will close the `modal`.

The only element that will not trigger this event is `<div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">`, that is the  modal content `div` where the content (title, text, fotter) are displayed.

Comment: This is great, thanks for that! I didn't realize there was a div overlay that contained the modal

Comment: @AngeliqueTaloyo That's nice! Please don't forget to mark this as accepted answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the `var modal = document.getElementById('id01');` with the modal you are seeing in the example.

The modal in the variable is the gray overlay on top of the page. It covers the entire page as a blank canvas for the modal content.

The modal you want to hide is the div that is on top of that, the "modal content". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9dn5.png)

Clicking outside the "modal content" is effectively clicking on the gray div overlay, which in this example is referenced in the variable called modal.

Hope that makes sense.